# node-oracledb bind variable of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

Using the [node-oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb) package with node.js, I'm trying to delete a row in my oracle database that has a **null** value in it.  I need to be able to pass a **null** value in as a bind variable but it is throwing an error:

```
var query = "delete from table where event IS :event";
var bind_vars = [null];
connection.execute(query, bind_vars, { autoCommit: true }, function(error, results) {});
```

The error returned is

> { Error: ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword errorNum: 908, offset: 46 }

Comment: `IS NULL` is two keywords, not a keyword+variable.  Since bind values are for variables, you won't be able to bind in this context (as you found).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a bind variable for that...

Given the following table:

```
create table t (
  c number
);

insert into t values (1);
insert into t values (null);
insert into t values (3);
insert into t values (null);
insert into t values (5);

commit;
```

This should work:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('./dbConfig.js');

async function runTest() {
  let conn;

  try {
    conn = await oracledb.getConnection(config);

    let result;
    let value = 1;

    if (value === null) {
      result = await conn.execute('delete from t where c is null');
    } else { // other values should have a bind
      result = await conn.execute('delete from t where c = :value', [value]);
    }

    // Note that the work was not committed.
    console.log('Rows deleted:', result.rowsAffected);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (conn) {
      try {
        await conn.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

runTest();
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. Unfortunately, I'm building a class that needs to be able to query multiple tables and be flexible enough to handle all types. So it can't be hard coded.  I'm essentially looking for a way to pass a variable of type null as a bind

Comment: I don't know what you mean by hard coded. How does your class generate SQL? Why not generate the SQL that uses the correct conditions. See "Nulls with Comparison Conditions": https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Nulls.html#GUID-B0BA4751-9D88-426A-84AD-BCDBD5584071.

Answer (score 0):

what about change the query

```
var query = "delete from table where nvl(event, '__') = nvl(:event, '__')";
var bind_vars = [null];
connection.execute(query, bind_vars, { autoCommit: true }, function(error, results) {});
```

it change null column and value to another character
change (__) with your own character